# not able to fetch data from the db when

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

[image: screenshot]
I am getting an error when trying to fetch data from the database (the data exists in the db). I am able to perform the action when there is no data in the db.
This is my entities:

```
@Table(name = "tbl_task")
public class Task {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long taskId;
private String title;
private String description;
private Status status;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User assignee;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "task", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Comment> comments;
```

and:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_user")
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long userId;
private String name;
@Column(unique = true)
private String email;
private Active active;
private String password;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "assignee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Task> tasks;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Comment> comments;
```

the error is:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw 
exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write 
JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError); nested exception is 
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion 
(StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: 
com.tasksmanagement.entity.Task["assignee"]- 
>com.tasksmanagement.entity.User["tasks"]- 
>org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag[0]
```

This is the method:

```
    public List<TaskResponse> getAllTasks() {
    List<Task> tasks = taskRepository.findAll();
    return
```

tasks.stream().map(this::mapToTaskResponse).collect(Collectors.toList());
}

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Infinite recursion 
(StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: 
com.tasksmanagement.entity.Task["assignee"]- 
>com.tasksmanagement.entity.User["tasks"]-  <------- your problem is here. Task refers to user and user back to task. This creates recursion. Refactor that out and you should be good to go.

Comment: thanks for your reply. any idea why is that happening and how to fix it? is it something to do with the OneToMany?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added @JsonManagedReference in the User class (List tasks field)
and added @JsonBackReference in the Task class (User asignee field) and it solved the issue